# How to group components in Doxygen, but not in "Modules"?

Tags: doxygen

I want to have groups hierarchy like this site (Eigen):
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/

I tried to do this with Doxygen group mechanism, but it is being under "Modules".

Instead, I want that the group would be under manual page hierarchy, like the example I gave above.

I've read the documentation, try to use some Doxygen commands, even tried to mimic Eigen, but with no success.

How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution thanks to Eigen forums help, and a bit of work by myself.

The solution is to use layout XML file for doxygen, and change "Modules" to whatever you want.

[Here is the manual for layout XML file](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout)

Eigen just switched "Modules" to "Chapters" in their [layout file](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/a0661a2bb16512dc4359c243db1dbeb9bc32b266/doc/eigendoxy_layout.xml.in?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default):

```
<tab type="modules" visible="yes" title="Chapters" intro=""/>
```

This seems the only whey to do this :-)